# Verificar estilo da PALAVRA no DOCX via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando verificar um documento (.DOCX)
[image: Documento Word (arquivo.docx)]

E pegar o texto que esteja com um determinado Estilo.
Acontece que o código que cheguei nas minhas tentativas só consegue pegar o paragrafo inteiro.
Gostaria de pegar parte do paragrafo que tem um Estilo diferente.

```
import os
import re
from docx import Document

document = Document('C:/Pastas/Arquivo.docx')

for p in document.paragraphs:

    if p.style.name == 'Estilo_Procurado':
        print(p.text)
    else:
        print("Outro Estilo")
```

[image: Saída do código acima]

Utilizando o `.runs` consegui achar o estilo em parte de um paragrafo, mas ao aplica o `if` ele não encontra o estilo e assim não consigo pegar o texto.

```
import os
import re
from docx import Document

document = Document('C:/Pastas/Arquivo.docx')

for p in document.paragraphs:

    for r in p.runs:
        if r.style.name == 'Estilo_Procurado':
            print(r.text)
        else:
            print("Outro estilo")
```

[image: Saída do código acima]

Comment: Sem a entrada do seu problema fica complicado elaborar uma resposta efetiva. Forneça o arquivo `.docx` em questão.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, você consegue entender o problema agora?

Comment: Você poderia disponibilizar uma amostra desse arquivo ?

Comment: Não consigo carregar o arquivo por aqui, mas vc pode criar qualquer arquivo word e preencher com textos aleatórios e mudar o Estilo de alguma parte, como fiz pra testar o códigos.

Answer (score -1):

Faça este teste

```
for r in p.runs:
        print(r.style.name)
        if r.style.name == 'Estilo_Procurado':
            print('igual',r.text)
        else:
            print('diferente',r.text)
```

Talvez seu problema seja de string, algum caractere diferente a string será diferente

Comment: Ele imprimiu o documento inteiro com um **diferente** na frente de cada `run`.
Isso pq o `if` não pega o Estilo na `run` por algum motivo.

Comment: Exatamente, agora você procura o 'Estilo_Procurado' e verifica se tem ele. Se tiver verifique porque está diferente da string 'Estilo_Procurado'

Comment: Quando vc manda exibir o nome do estilo na `run` ele mostra:

`for r in p.runs:
         print(r.style.name)`

**Default Paragraph Font/
Estilo_procurado Char**

Comment: Ou seja, ele mostra o nome o nome do estilo mas com o `if` ele não encontra.
Por isso ao rodar seu código todos os `runs` caiu no `else`.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, vê se ficou mais claro minha dúvida..